# PayPal Vault transaction fee/charges

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am using PayPal Vault service for transferring amount from stored Credit Card to a PayPal pro account.

Here is the document link that I followed: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-vault-overview.

After successful integration, I have checked it is charging $5.9% transaction fee, while I have heard that PayPal charges are just 2.9% in case of a pro account.

Please confirm Fee Charges for PayPal Vault service for this transfer of money from Credit card to PayPal account.
Any answers and suggestions would be
highly appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't matter what other users on SO think about what paypal services. What matters is what **paypal** thinks their fees are. In other words: this question is simply not making any sense. Contact the people owning the service you intend to use; and get clear with **them** about **their** conditions. Anything else is 2nd hand hearsay.

Comment: Yes, I am agree. I have already shared the same information to PayPal support team but I have post question here because if any body faced same problem then I can get quick solution and I got then I can update for future/other help.

Comment: Chances are that such information outdates quickly. This site is about **programming problems**; and not about legal / licencing issues for some external commercial service.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from PayPal service support.
        your monthly donations received determine the assessed fee amount:
        If your monthly donations are $0 to $3,000, the rate is 2.9% + $0.30.
        If your monthly donations are $3,000+ to $10,000, the rate is 2.5% + $0.30.
        If your monthly donations are $10,000+ to $100,000, the rate is 2.2% + $0.30.
        If your monthly donations are $100,000+, call us at 1-888-818-3928 for pricing.

And PayPal are not taking 5.6% charge it's taking if you are placed an order or 0 to 3000 USD than it's taking 2.9% of total amount and .30 per transaction fee.